# Outlook thinks firebase password reset link is a security issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

One of our customers requested a password reset. When they try to view the email in Microsoft Outlook, it complains that it thinks the the site is malicious. Has anyone experienced this, and if so, how was it resolved?

Comment: Are you using a custom domain for the email address?

Comment: No we're not. I tried setting it up with all the correct dns settings but verification failed. Would this help solve the issue?